# How to make a mothly report using Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

My table

> tblEmployeeScan(EMPLOYEE_ID varchar(7), ScannedTime)

Everyday each employee scans 2 times, 1 time or  0 time
Now I want to crate store procedure

```
Create proc spMonthScanReport
@MONTH int,
@YEAR int
```

which returns a mothly report like belows

```
EMPLOYEE ID         1   2   3       4   ….  31  (All days in month)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1000000 FIRST TIME  01/01/2014 6:00 02/01/2014 6:10                 
1000000 SECOND TIME 01/01/2014 15:00    02/01/2014 14:00                    
1000002 FIRST TIME  01/01/2014 7:00 02/01/2014 6:10                 
1000002 SECOND TIME 01/01/2014 15:00    02/01/2014 14:00                    
1000003 FIRST TIME      02/01/2014 6:10                 
1000003 SECOND TIME 01/01/2014 15:00
```

Please help me.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look into some articles regarding PIVOT, technical articles and some SO posts with answers. It is not all that hard, you just need to know how PIVOT works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea. This is not a production solution, I.e. it doesn't take account of more than two scans in a day or dates spanning across months etc.

```
    create table EmployeeScan
    (
        EMPLOYEE_ID varchar(7),
        ScanDate datetime
    )

    insert  EmployeeScan
        (EMPLOYEE_ID, ScanDate)
    values
        ('100', '01/01/2014 6:00'),
        ('100', '01/01/2014 15:00'),
        ('200', '01/01/2014 6:00'),
        ('200', '01/01/2014 15:00'),
        ('100', '01/02/2014 6:10'),
        ('100', '01/02/2014 15:30'),
        ('200', '01/02/2014 6:08'),
        ('200', '01/03/2014 7:12'),
        ('100', '01/31/2014 6:00')

    select
        es.EMPLOYEE_ID,
        row_number() over (partition by es.EMPLOYEE_ID, datepart(day, es.ScanDate) order by es.ScanDate) ScanCout,
        es.ScanDate,
        datepart(day, es.ScanDate) DayOfScan
    from
        EmployeeScan as es

    select
        EMPLOYEE_ID,
        ScanCout,
        [1] as Day1,
        [2] as Day2,
        [3] as Day3,
        [31] as Day31
    from
        (
            select
                es.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                row_number() over (partition by es.EMPLOYEE_ID, datepart(day, es.ScanDate) order by es.ScanDate) ScanCout,
                es.ScanDate,
                datepart(day, es.ScanDate) DayOfScan
            from
                EmployeeScan as es
        ) as scans pivot ( max(ScanDate) for DayOfScan in ([1], [2], [3], [31]) ) as pvtTable
    order by
        EMPLOYEE_ID,
        ScanCout

    drop table EmployeeScan
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Eugene, however day run from 1 to 31

Comment: Add the other days and please accept (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it is appropriate